# Why AppCompatActivity not exist after implement firebase

Tags: android, firebase

After implement Firebase on my two projects, `AppCompatActivity` along with `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` and `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` are not found.

I've been looking for five hours. And even after removing the implementation it doesn't work.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.pc.livium"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

Comment: Did you try clean and syncing the project again?

Comment: If you are using androidx you should update your libraries.
Did you tried to clean+rebuild project?

Comment: No work, no work

Comment: current versions of Firebase libraries use `androidx` dependencies... either migrate `com.android.support` to `androidx` - or downgrade Firebase dependencies to a version which still use `com.android.support`. voted to close this, because as it is written, this is not reproducible - you're talking about Firebase, but not having listed one single Firebase dependency (therefore cached libraries do not seem unlikely). `com.anjlab.android.iab.v3` might require to enable the Jetifier. besides "not working" is not an error description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
 1. Build -> Clean project than Build -> Rebuild Project
```

if that doe not help

```
2. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart (Take a few minutes to perform)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX…` and migrate your project to AndroidX.

AppCompat is deprecated, your `build.gradle` should look something like this under `depenedencies {}`:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` isn't deprecated ...neither documentation nor IDE indicate that.